# Anderswo vs. woanders

Tags: word-usage, synonym

Mir kommt es so vor, dass diese beiden Wörter ("anderswo" und "woanders") Synonyme sind. Ist das richtig? Gibt es ein Gegenbeispiel? Und ist das Zufall, dass "wo" einmal Suffix und einmal Präfix ist?

Beispiel: "Anderswo / Woanders ist Linksverkehr.", "Kannst du mir helfen, anderswo / woanders eine neue Existenz aufzubauen?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die beiden Wörter sind von der Bedeutung her identisch.

Der eigentliche Unterschied ergibt sich meiner Meinung nach aus dem Gesprochenen, der Betonung :

Ánderswó klingt poetisch, etwas erhaben, für ein Gedicht oder einen Liedtext passend.

Woánders lässt sich schneller und bequemer aussprechen und ist daher meiner Meinung nach in der Alltagssprache weiter verbreitet.

"Nein, wir gehn jetzt nicht anderswo hin" - der Anfang von "anderswo" erzeugt ein kleines Stocken im Sprachfluss, eine minimale extra Anstrengung, wohingegen sich

"Nein, wir gehn jetzt nicht woanders hin"  schön in einem Zug herunternuscheln lässt.

Anmerkung: das obengenannte Argument gilt eigentlich nicht, wenn das Wort am Satzanfang steht.
Würde ich vorher darüber nachdenken, ob ich "Anderswo ist Linksverkehr" oder "Woanders ist Linksverkehr" sage, würde ich mich für ersteres entscheiden, da es besser und flüssiger klingt; ohne nachzudenken würde ich aber zweiteres sagen, da "anderswo" in meinem täglichen gesprochenen Wortschatz einfach nicht vorkommt.

Answer (score 3):

Die Bedeutung ist dieselbe. In Büchern findet sich bis Ende des 20. Jahrhunderts überwiegend *anderswo*, seither dominiert *woanders* (Quelle: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anderswo%2Cwoanders&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3)):

[image]

Inzwischen scheint *anderswo* als umgangssprachlich empfunden zu werden ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anderswo), [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anderswo)), während *woanders* als standardsprachlich gilt ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/woanders), [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/woanders)).

Comment: Erstaunlicherweise hält der Grimm noch *woanders* für regional/umgangssprachlich.

Comment: @tofro Könntest du das verlinken? In der Onlineausgabe ist *woanders* noch nicht neu bearbeitet und auf dem Stand der Ausgabe von 1960. Dort ist nichts von umgangssprachlich zu lesen. Wo findest du das?

Comment: Unter "wo", dann von dort aus nach "woanders" suchen. Beim Eintrag für "woanders" steht nichts davon

Comment: @tofro Ich finde das nicht. Könntest du den Link posten?